# Create table using D3.js based on (hidden) JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am trying to create a table using D3.js and a JSON file.

The data itself consists of 6 columns: code, name, unit, value, target and norm. The table should only show three of them (name, target and value). I would like to use the values of the columns [code] and [norm] to identify the "id" and the "class".

The base code that I use is stated below. This code works fine to create the table itself - except for the "id" and "class" identification:

```
  var data = [{
    "code": 100,
    "name": "A",
    "unit": 12,
    "value": 0.6,
    "target": 0.75,
    "norm": "alert"
  }, {
    "code": 106,
    "name": "B",
    "unit": 12,
    "value": 0.6,
    "target": 0.75,
    "norm": "danger"
  }, {
    "code": 112,
    "name": "C",
    "unit": 12,
    "value": 0.9,
    "target": 0.75,
    "norm": "ok"
  }];

  var columns = ['name', 'target', 'value'];
  var table1 = d3.select('#table').append('table');

  var thead = table1.append('thead');
  var tbody = table1.append('tbody');

  // append the header row
  thead.append('tr')
    .selectAll('th')
    .data(["Name", "Target", "Value"])
    .enter()
    .append('th')
    .text(function(column) {
      return column;
    });

  // create a row for each object in the data
  var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('tr');

  // create a cell in each row for each column
  var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
    .data(function(row) {
      return columns.map(function(column) {
        return {
          column: column,
          value: row[column]
        };
      });
    })
    .enter()
    .append('td')
    .html(function(d) {
      return d.value;
    });

});
```

My desired table output is stated below where the JSON-values of [code] is used to identify the "id", [norm] is used for the "class". I can't seem to use data-elements 'at cell-level' that are not used to fill the table (td) value. How can I achieve this?

```
<div id="table">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Target</th>
        <th>Value</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="100" class="alert">A</td>
        <td>0.75</td>
        <td>0.6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="106" class="danger">B</td>
        <td>0.75</td>
        <td>0.6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="112" class="ok">C</td>
        <td>0.75</td>
        <td>0.9</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the columns mapping for the `td`s, you can add a couple more keys as `id` and `class`:

i.e.

```
var columns = ['name', 'target', 'value'], column_id = 'code', column_class = 'norm';
 ....   
 ....

return columns.map(function(column) {
            return {
              column: column,
              value: row[column],
              id: row[column_id],
              class: row[column_class]
            };
          });
```

And add it to the `td`s as follows:

```
.attr('id', function(d) { return d.column === 'name' ? d.id : null; })
.attr('class', function(d) { return d.column === 'name' ? d.class : null; })
```

Here's a snippet combining all of the above:

```js
 var data = [{
    "code": 100,
    "name": "A",
    "unit": 12,
    "value": 0.6,
    "target": 0.75,
    "norm": "alert"
  }, {
    "code": 106,
    "name": "B",
    "unit": 12,
    "value": 0.6,
    "target": 0.75,
    "norm": "danger"
  }, {
    "code": 112,
    "name": "C",
    "unit": 12,
    "value": 0.9,
    "target": 0.75,
    "norm": "ok"
  }];

  var columns = ['name', 'target', 'value'], column_id = 'code', column_class = 'norm';
  var table1 = d3.select('#table').append('table');

  var thead = table1.append('thead');
  var tbody = table1.append('tbody');

  // append the header row
  thead.append('tr')
    .selectAll('th')
    .data(["Name", "Target", "Value"])
    .enter()
    .append('th')
    .text(function(column) {
      return column;
    });

  // create a row for each object in the data
  var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('tr');

  // create a cell in each row for each column
  var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
    .data(function(row) {
      return columns.map(function(column) {
        return {
          column: column,
          value: row[column],
          id: row[column_id],
          class: row[column_class]
        };
      });
    })
    .enter()
    .append('td')
    .attr('id', function(d) { return d.column === 'name' ? d.id : null; })
    .attr('class', function(d) { return d.column === 'name' ? d.class : null; })
    .html(function(d) {
      return d.value;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>


<div id="table">

</div>
```

Hope this helps. :)